# Python package installation issue

Tags: python, pip

I'm installing packages using pip on CMD. When I tried to import the same library in the pycharm again it's asking me to install.Why? I installed in the same machine right? HOw to overcome this?

NOTE: I'm using python 3.9.2 & pip version is 21.1.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you activate your virtualenv directory?

Comment: In case you have multiple instance of Python / virtual environment configured, is PyCharm configured to use the same Python environment? Also, after you install some packages using command prompt, if PyCharm is configured correctly it will sense the change and start loading the changes, there should be a small status bar at the bottom of your PyCharm window?

Comment: @StanleyUlili: When I run the below code, I got two answers.                       
import sys
print(sys.prefix)                                                                                                                                    C:\Users\rpremala003\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/rpremala003/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/PythonLibraries/matplotlibrary.py
C:\Users\rpremala003\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv

Answer (score 0):

You can manually install packages on PyCharm.

```
settings > python interpreter > click on add symbol and enter the package your looking for
```